# Custom Functions are slower than built-in ones

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

Custom Functions are always slower than Built-in functions!

What is the secret?

and is there any way to access the code that is written for Built-in functions to see how they differ from custom ones???

Comment: `is there any way to access the code that is written for Built-in functions to see how they differ from custom ones???` Not that I am aware of.

Comment: Custom Functions are always slower than built-in functions>>>I've read this in the book "Excel 2010 Power Programming with VBA" by John Walkenbach

Comment: Yes you are correct. I had already edited my comment. I read it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Custom functions written in VBA will always be slower than built-in functions, yes. That's because the built-in functions are written in (presumably) C, which is compiled into optimized machine code, whereas VBA functions are interpreted. (Strictly speaking, they're "compiled" into an intermediate language prior to execution, but still - it's not machine code).

Comment: Oh so that's the secret,, I thought that excel is written using VBA

Comment: @Gary McGill your name is familiar to me, do you publish books?

Comment: @MohammadTaha: no, I don't publish anything. You may just have seen my name before on SO, I guess.

Comment: *`Oh so that's the secret,, I thought that excel is written using VBA`* - this made my day ;)